# Find the force during the accelerating part of a chin up

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

When you do a chinup, you raise your chin just over a bar (the chinning bar), supporting
yourself with only your arms. Typically, the body below the arms is
raised by about 30 cm in a time of 1.0 s, starting from rest. Assume
that the entire body of a 700 N person doing chin-ups is raised by
30 cm, and that half the 1.0 s is spent accelerating upward and the other
half accelerating downward, uniformly in both cases. Draw a free-body
diagram of the person’s body, and use it to find the force his arms must
exert on him during the accelerating part of the chin-up

---

$t = 0.5\ s$, $F_{g} = mg = 700 N$, $\Delta y = 0.30\ m$

We only have two forces acting in the y-direction. I define positive y up. Using Newton's 2nd law we get:

$$ \sum F_{y} = F_{chinup} - F_g = ma \iff F_{chinup} = ma + F_{g} $$

To get the acceleration I use that $\Delta y = v_{0}t + \frac{1}{2}at^{2}$ with $v_{0} = 0,\ \Delta y = 0.3\ m,\ t = 0.5\ s$ and get

$$ a = \frac{2 \cdot 0.3}{0.5^{2}} = 8 \cdot 0.3  = 2.4\ \ m/s^{2}$$

Plugging all the values into the first equation I obtain

$$ F_{chinup} = ma + F_{g} = \frac{700}{\underbrace{g}_\text{= 9.80}}2.4 + 700 = 871\ N$$

but the answer is $786\ N$ according to the book.

I do not know where I am going wrong.

Comment: What is the distance covered in each half of the 30 cm total lift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've interpreted the question incorrectly:

> Typically, the body below the arms is raised by about 30 cm in a time of 1.0 s

So $\Delta t$ is not $0.5\text{s}$. The person is, accelerating for $0.5\text{s}$ and then decelerating for the next $0.5 \text{s}$ and in the entire cycle, covers a total distance of $30 \text{cm}$.

Hint: Take advantage of the symmetry in the question : half the total time interval for acceleration combined with the fact that the person starts from rest

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm, it seems so yeah. I still don't entirely get how `raised by about 30 cm` would include the part where we lower our body. I just interpreted it as we raise our up 30 cm during the upwards part. Anyawy, using 0,15 instead of 0.3 gives the correct answer. So thanks.

Answer (score -2):

disclaimer: I am 15 and don't know that much about physics so I'm probably wrong.

I am going to assume your math is correct because i don't feel like doing it myself. I believe that where you are going wrong is that you are doing the math in a similar way to what it would take for a human to lift the weight of themselves. In reality, when people do a chin up, people who know what they are doing usually swing their lower body in ways that allow them to gain upwards momentum. With this in mind, the real force required isn't pulling a dead weight upwards, it is catching yourself around 3/4s of the way up and finishing it. Also, the human body's muscles produce different amounts of force depending on their positioning. Overall, I believe this is a simple matter of people using external forces outside of their arms to help lift themselves up which the book that you are referencing does not account for. It also doesn't account for momentum. Sorry if I'm totally wrong.

Comment: “I am going to assume your math is correct” - not a safe assumption !

Comment: Your body shouldn't be swinging around during a chinup - you've described the form of someone who *doesn't* know what they're doing. Regardless of what other muscles you use, any lifting force must go through the arms and ultimately come from interaction with the bar. If you didn't need to exert force through your arms to accelerate upward, you could jump into the air, and keep accelerating upwards by swinging your body around.